# Liquid coming from seat belt connectors

Tags: honda, accord, leak, seat-belt

[image]I have a brown liquid coming from somewhere near the seatbelt connectors in the rear side of the car. Checked the trunk, nothing seems to have seeped in. Please help me with what could be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there anyway you could take a picture and post it here? It really depends on where it's leaking from (exactly) and what color it is. If you take a clean white paper towel and wipe part of the liquid up, taking a pic of it and posting it here would help as well. Also, what year is your Accord? Does it have a manual or automatic transmission?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Its a Honda Accord 2005, it has an automatic transmission

Comment: Are you sure something didn't leak out of some container onto the seat belt? There is nothing back there which could be leaking onto your belt. All liquids are up front in the engine compartment which could cause any kind of stain.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 : There was nothing kept in there that was leaking. And its strange as all the seat belt connectors on the back are having the same problem. One more thing to notice the gap near of the seat belts are wet. I have wrapped some napkins to these seat belts so save my seats from staining. This liquid is sticky though and has no odor.

Comment: That is very strange ... no clue as there shouldn't be anything there to leak out from the clasps. The *only* thing I can think of is if someone got industrious and decided they needed some kind of lubricant or rust preventative put onto them. Really, the seat belts should have no liquid in them at all. If what has come out of them was grease someone put in there, I guess I could see that.

Comment: Alright... will check with a mechanic to help me with this. Thank you @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Answer (score 1):

It could be  from underneath the seat from accumulation of water originating from a rusted section of the wheel well . If there is a hole in the wheel well a spinning tire on a rainy day would propel water inside. It then accumulates and wicks up in the seat and exiting the seat belt hole. A body shop technician would confirm this and offer a repair solution. Not unexpected on a 14 year old car.